# How to customize build setting based on architecture in Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, cpu-architecture

I need to customize some build settings (namely linker flags) in `Xcode` based on whether the build is for architecture `arm64` or `armv7`.  I upgraded to `Xcode 7.2` and it seems there is no longer this option:

As usual, you can expand any setting to see Debug and Release tabs, then if you click `+`, you will see pop up menu with `Any Architecture|Any SDK` on top, but inside the menu I only see options for different OSs and SDKs like `iOS 9.2`, `Any iOS`, `Mac OS X`, etc.  I chose `Any iOS` since I need to support older iOS versions, but I don't see a way to choose `arm64` and `armv7`, on which I need to customize.

Am I missing something, or did `Xcode` really remove this option now?

I suppose if this is no longer working, the only other way I see to customize is to create additional target, which is not very convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do is to create a new xcconfig file for your target. (if you're using `Cocoapods` you might want to `include` it as well).

And then you can specify the architecture as well as the sdk for a build setting like this:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[sdk=iphoneos*][arch=arm64] = $(inherited) "-D" "COCOAPODS"
```

Check [this](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html) tutorial for more information.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah this seems to be the only way.